# Sum up in a list of list properties

Tags: c#

I have below structure where I would like to sum up a list of properties

```
public class Space
{       
    public AirBalance AirBalance { get; set; } = new();      
}

public class AirBalance
{
    public bool AllowVariableExhaust { get; set; }
    public SpaceVentilationAirflow VentilationAirflow { get; set; } = new();
}
public class SpaceVentilationAirflow 
{
    public List<A621VentilationAirflow> A621VentilationAirflows { get; set; } = new();
}

public class A621VentilationAirflow 
{
    public double BreathingZoneVentilation { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to sum up all spaces of A621VentilationAirflow's BreathingZoneVentilation, and I have a value of 1115.05 for breathing zone ventilation. When I sum up using the below code, it always gives me the same value even If I have two spaces and a list of `A621VentilationAirflow` objects that exist.

```
 Spaces?.Sum(a => a?.AirBalance?.VentilationAirflow?.A621VentilationAirflows.Sum(a => a.BreathingZoneVentilation))
```

Could anyone please let me know where I am doing wrong with the above code? Many thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show your consuming code? That is, the code where you actually use an instance of the Space class and the values you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like you need to change your code to:

```cs
 Spaces?.Sum(a => a?.AirBalance?.VentilationAirflow?.A621VentilationAirflows.Sum(b => b.BreathingZoneVentilation))
```

Also, using projection (Select / SelectMany) you can get a more readable (imo) query:

```cs
        var y = spaces
            .Select(c => c.AirBalance)
            .Select(c => c.VentilationAirflow)
            .SelectMany(c => c.A621VentilationAirflows)
            .Sum(c => c.BreathingZoneVentilation);
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/RBX9aX

Comment: I agree that select/selectmany is better than sum. It's much easier to read